# Fetch data on nestjs module before initialating it

Tags: javascript, types, nestjs

so I'm trying to create a kafka client and my credentials are on aws KMS, so i need to fetch my sasl username and password before starting my module.

Does anyone know how to fetch data on a module fisrt? Thanks

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'producer',
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
        options: {
          client: {
            clientId: 'messages',
            brokers: [...BROKERS.split(',')],
            ssl: {
              rejectUnauthorized: false,
            },
            sasl: {
              mechanism: 'scram-sha-512',
              username, // This is what i want to fetch
              password, // This is what i want to fetch
            },
          },
          consumer: {
            groupId: 'client',
            sessionTimeout: 60000,
            minBytes: 5,
            maxBytes: 40000000,
          },
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [ProducerController],
  providers: [ProducerService],
})
export class ProducerModule {}
```

Since this is executed right after a nest run, i cant use an await to first load this on my dotenv and then access it, so i need an asnync way

Comment: have you tried to use the `onModuleInit` hook? it would resolve the value of some provider that will be injected into a facade dynamic module that wrappers the `ClientsModule.register` one

Comment: onModuleInit goest after module declaration, so i still get username and password undefined

Comment: you would move that `ClientsModule.register` to another module, and then import it into `ProducerModule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I made it, so you can use an async function in the module!

```
@Module({
 imports: [yourFunction()], // Made an async func and works!
 controllers: [ProducerController],
 providers: [ProducerService],
})
export class ProducerModule {}
```